# How to test scrollIntoView in RTL and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

i am trying to test `scrollIntoVew` event. There is a Explore Cars button and when we click it, it scrolls the page to the discover section. I saw couple of similar questions and i found this approach:

```
const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock();
```

This kinda worked for me. The unit test is passing. The problem is when i remove click event, it is also passing. Why?

Component:

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";

import { CustomButton } from "@/components";

const Hero: React.FC = () => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const nextSection = document.getElementById("discover");

    if (nextSection) {
      nextSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="hero">
      <div className="flex-1 pt-36 padding-x">
        <h1 className="hero__title">
          Find, book, rent a car—quick and super easy!
        </h1>

        <p className="hero__subtitle">
          Streamline your car rental experience with our effortless booking
          process.
        </p>

        <CustomButton
          title="Explore Cars"
          containerStyles="bg-primary-blue text-white rounded-full mt-10"
          handleClick={handleScroll}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="hero__image-container">
        <div className="hero__image">
          <Image src="/hero.png" alt="hero" fill className="object-contain" />
        </div>

        <div className="hero__image-overlay" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Unit Test (passed):

```
  it("scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked", () => {
    render(<Hero />);

    const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock();

    const buttonElement = screen.getByText("Explore Cars");
    userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Unit Test without click event (passed):

```
  it("scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked", () => {
    render(<Hero />);

    const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock();

    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you called the `scrollIntoViewMock` function in the test case. It should be:

```
const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;
```

e.g.

```
import React from 'react';

const Hero = () => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const nextSection = document.getElementById('discover');

        if (nextSection) {
            nextSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='discover'>discover</div>
            <button onClick={handleScroll}>Explore Cars</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Hero;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Hero from '.';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';

it('scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked', async () => {
    render(<Hero />);

    const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;

    const buttonElement = screen.getByText('Explore Cars');
    await userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked', () => {
    render(<Hero />);

    const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;

    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76961197/index.test.tsx (6.247 s)
  ✓ scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked (51 ms)
  ✓ scrolls to the next section when Explore Cars button is clicked (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.478 s, estimated 7 s
```